# Mensaje de error: "Cannot GET [ruta del recurso]" cuando trato de servir un archivo estatico por medio de express sin dar un alias al directorio

Tags: nodejs, express

Estoy estudiando node y express, estoy tratando de devolver una imagen que se encuentre en el directorio `img` de mi sitio web.

El problema es que el programa solo me funciona si agrego un alias de ruta y no si doy directamente el directorio como tal.

¿Podrian decirme porque?

```
let ExpressFramework = require("express")

let ExpressApp = ExpressFramework()
ExpressApp.use(ExpressFramework.static("img"))

ExpressApp.listen(9000,function () {
    console.log(" I'm listening, hurry mario save the princess")
})
```

Mi aprendizaje acerca de este tema lo obtuve de aca: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/Introduction#Serving_static_files

Y pues aquí si lo hacen con el nombre real del directorio

El error que me sale cuando trato de acceder al recurso es el siguiente:

```
Cannot GET /img/img.jpg
```

Este error se me pinta en el navegador cuando trato de pedir el recurso introduciendo la url

Mi comprensión acerca de `static("directorio")` es que devuelve una función que servirá de callback para `use(callback)` y se ejecutara cuando llegue una petición con cualquier método `HTTP` pero con un recurso necesitado que este en img

**Carpeta del proyecto:** Centro

**Contenido:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En el árbol de archivos de tu proyecto, la carpeta img, ¿Dónde se encuentra? podrías pintar un poco del árbol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con Express, tienes que crear una ruta que controle y maneje todos los archivos y/o imágenes. Por defecto, Express ( O cualquier servicio web basado en node.js ) no sirven archivos, sólo interpretan código, y esto solo será posible si agregas un controlador de archivos estáticos.

Ya tienes la respuesta, debes declarar un alias de la ruta

```
ExpressApp.use(ExpressFramework.static("img"))
```

Esto como medida de seguridad y evitar la exposición de tu árbol de archivos del servidor.

**¿Te imaginas pedir el index.js?**

Esta pregunta la hice en el foro inglés hace un par de meses, espero te puedas guiar.

[Get image from localhost to localhost with express and nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56783679/get-image-from-localhost-to-localhost-with-express-and-nodejs)